# unittest assertionError in python AssertionError: <Response [200]> != 200

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests, python-unittest

I'm writing python tests with unittest and requests modules but getting 
`AssertionError: <Response [200]> != 200`

Tests are setup in two functions, test_get and test_post. Test runners starts from Tests class, where the issue is within test2. I've tried to assert this also: `<Response [200]>` also. But getting this Error instead:

```
<Response [200]> != <Response [200]>

Expected :<Response [200]>
Actual   :<Response [200]>
```

For this I am using httpbin and pycharm.

```
import requests
import unittest

# Test 1: Assert get data body
get_url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
test_get = \
    {
        'args': {},
        'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Host': 'httpbin.org',
                    'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.21.0'},
        'origin': '94.255.130.105, 94.255.130.105',
        'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'
    }

def get_httpbin(get_url):
    r = requests.get(get_url).json()
    return r

# Test 2: Assert post is OK 200
post_url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
test_post = \
    {
        'sender': 'Alice',
        'receiver': 'Bob',
        'message': 'We did it!'
    }

def post_httpbin(post_url):
    r = requests.post(post_url, test_post)
    return r

# Test Runner
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(get_httpbin(get_url), test_get)

    def test2(self):
        self.assertEqual(post_httpbin(post_url), 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing a response object with a number. They're not equal.

What you intend is to compare the *status code* from the response object with a number. Try this:

```
def test2(self):
    self.assertEqual(post_httpbin(post_url).status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now you are comparing `r` which gives you `<Response [200]>` with an integer, hence the asserion error. Instead you would want to assert `r.status_code`, which gives you the status code as an integer  with `200`.

```
def test2(self):
    self.assertEqual(post_httpbin(post_url).status_code, 200)
```